# How to open a link in new tab and then coming back to previous tab in webdriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium2, testng

I have a situation in which I have to perform some action on one web page and their changes will reflect in the other web page. And after that I want to check whether changes are reflecting or not by visiting the other web page. So is their any way to achieve this?

The point is both the web pages are of different application. I was willing to perform task on one web page in one tab and then opening other web page in other tab. If there is any other way to do this. kindly suggest.

Comment: Open a new window is no alternative?

Comment: a new window means another instance of browser. is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Actions` object to open a new tab. Perform a action who press and hold the `ctrl` key and after that press the `t` key. After that release all keys.

`ctrl` and `t` is the shortcut to open a new tab in the most browsers.

To switch between the tabs you use the following shortcut: `ctrl` and `TAB`.

Comment: I have never used JavascriptExecutor. Is there any specific thing I need to do with it or simply writing window.open will do the job.

Comment: @razizcool4all Updated the answer.

Comment: JS also opens a new browser instead of new tab. Anyways thanks will use shortcuts. I was just curious to know whether we have any direct option for that or not.

Comment: @razizcool4all Hmm... yes, you are right. With the first line will a new `WebDriver` instance created. Sorry, my mistake. Answer updated.